# Coverting Float to String with comma without Rounding

Tags: kotlin

I'm using this for adding commas into number.

```
val commaNumber = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(floatValue)
```

`floatValue` is `8.1E-7` , but `commaNumber` shows just 0.

How to covert Float to String with comma without Rounding?

Comment: What do you mean by "String with comma"? What is the string that you want?

Comment: @Sweeper if number is `10035.312` , I want `"10,035.312"` .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the US locale, the `maximumFractionalDigits` of the number format is 3, therefore, it will try to format 8.1e-7 with only 3 fractional digits, which makes it 0.000. Since the `minimumFractionalDigits` is also 0, it tries to remove all the unnecessary 0s, making the final result "0".

You should set `maximumFractionalDigits` to at least 7 if you want to precisely display the number 8.1e-7.

```
val numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US)
numberFormat.maximumFractionDigits = 7
val commaNumber = numberFormat.format(floatValue)
```

As for the commas, that is already part of the US locale. It uses grouping, and `,` is its grouping separator. The commas will be inserted if they are needed.